# The arabic letter not displaying correctly using aero report in openerp v7

Tags: openerp-7, openoffice.org, aeroolib

I'm making a new report in openerp v7, from OpenOffice using aero report.

[image]

when i choose pdf as output, the report not displaying arabic letter correctly
[image]

if i choose odt they displaying correctly

[image]

My problem is , how can i displaying arabic letter correctly, using aero report, Thank in advance!

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of the "save as" or "export" or "pdf options" you have in the used software?

Comment: Can you show your font mappings under 'Settings > Configuration > General Settings > Report Font'

Comment: @Jaya, I use Times New Roman

Answer (score 0):

You issue is font setting. Please correct below settings:

1. Set NLS_LANG=ARABIC_EGYPT.AR8MSWIN1256 (or AR8ISO8859P6 on UNIX).
2. Set REPORTS_PATH to the font directory in which the TrueType font exists. For example, C:\WINNT\fonts.
3. Open the uifont.ali file and edit the [PDF:Subset] section to specify the TrueType font name.

```html
[PDF:Subset]
"Andale Duospace WT J" = "Aduoj.ttf"
"Albany WT J"="AlbanWTJ.ttf"
```

Also for reference please use the below documentation:
[Using PDF in Oracle Reports](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14099_10/bi.1012/b14048/pbr_pdf.htm#i1005819)

Comment: Not sure if your configurations are complete. I would suggest to take a look at below document. It has complete setup steps.   http://am4computers.com/wordpress/archives/246